# Is this a valid approach to generalize logarithms for other fields?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, logarithms, group-homomorphism

You can define any logarithm with the following:
$$\log(xy)=\log(x)+\log(y)$$
$$\log(1)=0$$
and then just define $\log(b)=1$ for any base $b$. This looks like a group homomorphism
$$\log:\mathbb{R}^{\times}\to \mathbb{R}$$
where $\mathbb{R}^\times$ is $(0, \infty)$ under multiplication, and $\mathbb{R}$ is just the reals under addition, which is operation preserving by definition. What is sort of interesting is that these are "two parts of a field", one being the 'multiplicative part' and and the other being the 'additive part'. Anyways, my question is this:

> Can we apply this to any field $F$, as in can we define a group homomorphism $\log : F^\times \to F$, and get something that acts 'logarithmic'? More specifically, is this at all a good approach to generalize logarithms?

I see some problems with this, for example what would this look like for finite fields? Also, $\log$ only maps the positive reals under multiplication to the reals under addition, and lots of fields don't have a good notion of 'positive'. Is there any way to save this?

Comment: You can think of a modification like applying log function twice, or composed log as many times as you want, I hope that works, still not sure.

Comment: Okay no we can't do that

Comment: Because After applying the first log it's not in R invertable.

Comment: But the fun fact is we can apply log as many times as we want if we pertub the range and domain a bit like, $log : F^{X}-\{1\}\to F^{X}-\{1\}$ then it's not a field homomorphism but it's cool.